# Trait problem: Borrowed data escapes outside of associated function

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am trying to implement a binary tree. I want the node data to be separate, because there are many different ways in which this can be implemented, while algorithms on the tree should be generic and independent of how the data is stored.

But I am running into a weird issue with the borrow checker. Basically, when I switch `impl<TValue> Display for dyn Tree<TValue>` with `impl<TValue> Display for TreeNode<TValue>`, the problem goes away. But I have no idea why. Why is the Trait causing this issue?

My code is this:

```
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter};

struct TreeNode<TValue> {
    value: TValue,
    left: Option<Box<TreeNode<TValue>>>,
    right: Option<Box<TreeNode<TValue>>>,
}

trait Tree<TValue> {
    fn value(&self) -> &TValue;
    fn left(&self) -> Option<&dyn Tree<TValue>>;
    fn right(&self) -> Option<&dyn Tree<TValue>>;
}

impl<TValue> Display for dyn Tree<TValue>
where
    TValue: Display,
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        f.write_str("(")?;
        Display::fmt(self.value(), f)?;
        f.write_str(", ")?;

        match self.left() {
            Some(ref x) => x.fmt(f)?,
            None => f.write_str("None")?,
        }

        f.write_str(", ")?;

        match self.right().as_ref() {
            Some(x) => x.fmt(f)?,
            None => f.write_str("None")?,
        }

        f.write_str(")")
    }
}

impl<TValue> Tree<TValue> for TreeNode<TValue>
where
    TValue: Display,
{
    fn value(&self) -> &TValue {
        &self.value
    }

    fn left(&self) -> Option<&dyn Tree<TValue>> {
        self.left.as_ref().map(|x| &**x as &dyn Tree<TValue>)
    }

    fn right(&self) -> Option<&dyn Tree<TValue>> {
        self.right.as_ref().map(|x| &**x as &dyn Tree<TValue>)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tree = Box::new(TreeNode {
        value: 1,
        left: Some(Box::new(TreeNode {
            value: 2,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        })),
        right: Some(Box::new(TreeNode {
            value: 3,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        })),
    }) as Box<dyn Tree<i32>>;

    println!("{}", tree);
}
```

And the compiler prints:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of associated function
  --> src\main.rs:24:15
   |
19 |     fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
   |            -----
   |            |
   |            `self` declared here, outside of the associated function body
   |            `self` is a reference that is only valid in the associated function body
   |            let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
24 |         match self.left() {
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |               |
   |               `self` escapes the associated function body here
   |               argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

To me, this makes no sense. Nothing in the function body captures this value and tries to keep it beyond the scope of this function. Is this some borrow checker limitation?

Comment: This is a very confusing diagnostic so I think an issue should be filed regardless of the reason

Comment: other than the weird diagnostic, why do you need everything to be `dyn` ? should a left branch of a tree be able to be a tree of another type ?

Comment: also, from my testing, the error is introduced when you try to call `fmt` on  `x`, not when you do `self.left()`.

Comment: @Bamontan it's not a want. The compiler seems to force me to make this a trait object. I am not sure why. But if I don't use `dyn` in the Trait itself, then all other places will require `dyn` and `dyn` won't be usable because then `Tree` is not a trait object. It's weird. I believe there still are many blind spots in Rust's compiler messages.

Comment: not saying dynamic dispatch is bad, but is there something that prevent you from doing it this way: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=15f2521bc284468008aaeab63a863a93) ?

Comment: @Bamontan I am not sure why this didn't work for me, you seem to be trying what I was also trying. I will check tomorrow. Dynamic dispatch is actually bad in this case, because it isn't a zero-cost abstraction. And my tree algorithms should not force dynamic dispatch on everything.

Comment: only thing I could see to hold ypu back is that you wanted to implement `Display` for all types that impl `Tree`, and you can't do it with static dispatch, because you don't own the `Display` trait. note that the dyn way only implements `Display` for `dyn Tree`, not all types that implement `Tree`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some mental hoops that the compiler has to jump through to reason about your code. Spoilers, the reason is that when you have `dyn Tree<TValue>` (where you are implementing `Display`), the lifetime constraining the type defaults to `'static`. So when you call `x.fmt(f)`, the `x` type must be `'static` in order to implement the `fmt` method, and looking backwards means that the `self` used in `self.left()` to get `x` *must* be `'static` as well. But it's not, and thus the error.

The simple fix is to implement `Display` for `dyn Tree<TValue>` with any lifetime:

```
impl<'a, TValue> Display for dyn Tree<TValue> + 'a
```

Comment: Can be `for dyn Tree<TValue> + '_`. But what I don't understand here is that `self` is not `&'static dyn Tree`, it's `&'_ (dyn Tree + 'static)` and so this should work fine.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman because the signature of `.left()` is `fn<'a>(&'a self) -> Option<&'a (dyn Tree<TValue> + 'a)>` (elided lifetimes expanded). So even if `self` is `&'a (dyn Tree + 'static)`, the result of `.left()` is `&'a (dyn Tree + 'a)` (not `'static`). I lament that the elided lifetimes of trait objects are different depending on where they are written.

Comment: Oh true, I forgot that trait objects are invariant.