# Error occurs when required ToString trait removed (borrowed data escapes outside of method)

Tags: rust

I removed a ToString trait requirement from an generic impl of my own "Custom" trait.

```rust
impl<T : Any 
    // +ToString //uncommenting this removes the error
> CustomData for T { 
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any { self }    
}
```

Elsewhere:

```rust
impl CustomInstance {
    pub fn borrow<T:Any>(&self) -> Option<Ref<'_, T>>  {
        let b= self.data.borrow();

        if !b.as_any() //error here
            .is::<T>() 
        { 
            return None;
        }
        ..
    }
}
```

Now gives the error:

```
borrowed data escapes outside of method
`self` escapes the method body here
```

I found a similar post "[Trait problem: Borrowed data escapes outside of associated function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73495603/trait-problem-borrowed-data-escapes-outside-of-associated-function)"

that seems to say the required (ToString) trait defaults the lifetime to static, but I don't understand where to go from there.

Here is the full code (it has been shortened from the original):

```rust
use std::any::Any;
use std::cell::{RefCell, Ref};
use std::rc::Rc;

pub trait CustomData : Any { fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any; }

impl<T : Any 
    // +ToString //uncommenting this removes the error
> CustomData for T { 
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any { self }    
}

pub struct CustomInstance { data: Rc<RefCell<dyn CustomData>>, }

impl CustomInstance {
    pub fn borrow<T:Any>(&self) -> Option<Ref<'_, T>>  {
        let b= self.data.borrow();

        if !b.as_any() //error here
            .is::<T>() 
        { 
            return None;
        }
        
        Some(Ref::map(b, |c| c.as_any().downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap()))
    }
}

fn main() { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler thinks that you're calling `as_any()` on the `Ref` itself, not on the data it contains, and since the `Ref` is not `'static` it complains. When you constrain it with `ToString`, which `Ref` does not implement, it derefs it for you.

All you need is to deref the `Ref`:

```rust
pub fn borrow<T: Any>(&self) -> Option<Ref<'_, T>> {
    let b = self.data.borrow();

    if !(*b).as_any().is::<T>() {
        return None;
    }

    Some(Ref::map(b, |c| c.as_any().downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap()))
}
```

Or just use [`filter_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Ref.html#method.filter_map):

```rust
pub fn borrow<T: Any>(&self) -> Option<Ref<'_, T>> {
    let b = self.data.borrow();
    Ref::filter_map(b, |c| c.as_any().downcast_ref::<T>()).ok()
}
```